# Facebook graph API suddenly going very slow

Tags: facebook, performance, facebook-graph-api

I'm not really sure what's going on, but today I've noticed that the facebook api is working extremely slow for me.

At first I though it was a bug in my code, but I tried the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), and even that's causing timeout errors half the time (just using `/me`):

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Server timeout)

I don't think its my internet connection, since everything else seems to be working quickly, and http://speedtest.net is giving me good results.

- Is my problem somehow *fixable* or is this just some sort of freak occurance?
- Has this happened for anyone else?
- Do I need to consider the case that it will take exceedingly long in my application to recieve a response?

I currently have a registration page that waits for a FB.api response (with a spinner gif) before displaying the form.  I *could* use a timeout to wait a few seconds and show it if the api doesn't respond, but I'd really rather not have to use this same sort of logic in every api call that my application depends on...

**EDIT:** its spontaneously fixed itself now. still no clue what happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check facebook api live status with this URL

https://developers.facebook.com/live_status

> today at 11:13pm: API issues We're currently experiencing a problem
>   that may result in high API latency and timeouts. We are working on a
>   fix now.

Comment: Thanks for the link, was just wondering if something like that existed.  I think its probably safe to say that was the cause of my problems.  If no one else responds within an hour or two, I'll select this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yup, this is definitely it.  The time it was resolved coincided with when it started working again.  Thanks again Taha!

Comment: I have the same problem. My users can't login with facebook since 30 minutes.